# How To Increment a counter specific to its individual List in listview only? Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Hello I'm a beginner in flutter. I have a oproblem in my app where I want to add and individual counter for every list that is generated. So far my code would run the app so that if i click the list it would increment the numbers in the following list too. I dont want that I want it to increment individually. Can someone help please. It would be very much appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  //what you want to start whenever you start the function
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Post {
  String body;
  int likes = 0;
  bool hasbeenLiked = true;
  void likePost() {
    this.likes++;
  }
}

List<String> todoList = [];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Habit Tracker',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  var post = Post();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Habbit Tracker")),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('${todoList[index]}'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up_sharp),
                  subtitle: Text(post.likes.toString()),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      post.likePost();
                    });
                  },
                  onLongPress: () {
                    setState(() {
                      todoList.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: todoList.length,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
            controller: this.controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.brightness_1),
                hintText: "Enter your habit",
                suffixIcon: FloatingActionButton(
                    child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        todoList.add(controller.text);
                      });
                    })))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a button for each element in ListView. Then you can define the counter with the related button.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  //what you want to start whenever you start the function
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class Post {
  String body;
  String text; // I added to connect the text with the model "Post".
  int likes = 0;

  
  Post([this.text]); // This will be an optional parameter in the constructor of class.

  bool hasbeenLiked = true;
  void likePost() {
    this.likes++;
  }
}

List<Post> todoList = [];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Habit Tracker',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  var post = Post();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Habbit Tracker",
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text('${todoList[index].text}'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_circle_up_sharp),
                  subtitle: Text(todoList[index].likes.toString()),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      // Here, we have to like the indexed post.
                      todoList[index].likePost();
                    });
                  },
                  onLongPress: () {
                    setState(() {
                      todoList.removeAt(index);
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
              itemCount: todoList.length,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TextField(
          controller: this.controller,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.brightness_1),
            hintText: "Enter your habit",
            suffixIcon: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  // Here, we should add new model with parameter.
                  todoList.add(new Post(controller.text));
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And you have to connect your `todoList` with `post`.

Comment: Don't add vague answers. Use comments. And if you don't have access to use comments then kindly wait till you get enough repo to add a comment.

Comment: Also, try to add a little more explanation as it will be helpful for the OP to understand how exactly you did. :)

Comment: For some reason now when i click the + post it just says an instant of Post instead of showing the title. Any fixes for that ? How do you store the string inside the list of posts and get that out

Comment: It should work if you run the above code. Are you trying to modify the code?

Comment: And regarding storing of the text, we're creating an instance of type Post and then passing the text via constructor to the post and then storing the instance in the list.

Comment: @OMi Shah, I added comment lines that I did differently in code.

we inserted a member in our Post class to access and connect the string which is text. This is the correct way the use.

Comment: @OMi Shah, If you dont mind me asking since im very new at this stuff. where did the program know how to get the index for todoList[index]. My best guess is that it got it from the Item Builder. But how does item Builder know the length of the list and access 0,1,2,3.... and so on. My guess is that it got it from item count with the lenght of the todoList inside of it is that true?

Comment: You're right. You got it right. That's how it's working.